# How can i detect that user replied to my questions SendTextMessageAsync

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want to send multiple questions one by one (e.g. "What's your name?" "What's your city?" What's your mobile?", etc.) to my bot and the user must reply to them.

I don't know how I can do this. I'm using `Bot.SendTextMessageAsync`.

```
await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "What's your name?");
```

After this question I want to detect what's user reply and then I ask the next question,without using another if( like if(message.Text=="info") ).

```
private static async void BotOnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
{
    var message = messageEventArgs.Message;

    if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.TextMessage) return;

    if (message.Text=="info") 
    {
        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "What's your name?");
    }

    else
    {
        //this section happened after I ask from user

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please delete code that is not relevant to your question?

Comment: tnx to your reply.i deleted unrelevant code.

Comment: it seems to me that you need to store "conversation" for a user and based on that decide what question to ask.. but this is not done by the bot it should be done in your own code.

Comment: so in your opinion  there's no way to detect that what is the user reply to SendTextMessageAsync..it's so bad :(

Comment: there is allways some way.. But in this case there is no "built-in" mechanism that you may just copy-paste.